# Xamarin.Android Material Design Theming with Appcompat

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I am facing some bug with custom material theme with AppCompat
I already set the the target to android 5.0
I already download the android support repository through the android sdk manager
and I add the AppCompat packege already
I will provide you some screenschot so you might help me figure out what's going wrong with it. Thank you in advance 
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxf3V.png)

here is my style xml for the color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
                        <item name="colorPrimary">#9E9E9E</item>
                        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#616161</item>
                        <item name="colorAccent">#FF5252</item>
                        <item name="colorControlHighLight">#F5F5F5</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Try a clean & rebuild

Comment: it doesn't work and I have already try on several solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely running into an issue with the Support library Caches. We wrote a troubleshooting document on this topic that should help you resolve this:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

(Gist - https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/f6291eacd4da5f6aa4cd)

Answer (score 0):

Goto `C:\Users\Geeksan\AppData\Local\Xamarin` folder & Delete all folders corresponding to Android packages. Also delete zip files from the zips folder.

Then from your solution, add the required packages from nuget again & build the solution. The build process will take some time to download the zip files & unpack them. So wait for build to complete. Do not cancel the build process.